# How to create Azure Digital Twins backup and restore it in onter empty ADT account?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, backup, azure-digital-twins

I am new in Azure Digital Twins.
I have a task with the following requirements:

1. Export data from ADT one subscription
2. Import it to ADT in another subscription (which is empty).

First of all, I guess, I should create a backup of ADT data and then restore it in empty ADT subscription.

But how to do it? What should I do at first? Didn't meet this information in the Azure Digital Twins documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tyler is right that it isn't a feature built into the product.  The only thing I would add is that you could export a bunch of your topology and items in Digital Twins into a bunch of JSON files.  Then you could have this in your repo and import it into another solution, might need to strip out all of the IDs.  I have seen some customers where they have all of their types, and spaces/devices/senors all in their repo and during build/deployment time they push those to Digital Twins via the REST APIs.  This way they can reuse items between instances.  So you could do a bunch of GETs to get all of your items and then you would have that ready to put into another instance, again after clearing out the IDs.  Oh also note that you can do a /spaces PUT call with all of the payload as one big bulk call and it should put everything in there.  Hope some extra details here help!

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently a feature of Azure Digital Twins. If you would like to request it you can suggest it in [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/916621-azure-digital-twins).

You could make get api calls from one instance and post to another, but there is no way today to retain IDs between instances.